# ver cambios en una tabla sql server con php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

necesito ver si es posible saber cuando insertan un dato en una tabla x de mi base de datos usando php. El contexto es el siguiente: Existe una cinta por la cual pasan cajas , en  esta cinta estará ubicado un lector infrarrojo el cual detectara cada vez que pasa una caja por la cinta. Este lector opera con un software de un tercero , que insertara un dato en mi base de datos por cada caja que pase.
Entonces debo detectar cada vez que halla un cambio en mi tabla , para reflejar los cambios en mi sistema web.

el front end es con angular y el backend con php en apache y sql server.

Habia pensado en dejar corriendo un programa como servicio en php con un timer , para que consulte cada cierto tiempo la tabla.. pero no se si hay una mejor manera y tampoco si es factible.

Comment: La única forma de ver cambios en la base de datos es haciendo consultas a la misma, por lo que el timer puede ser la mejor opción.

Comment: creo que el timer seria mas factible para tu caso algo asi como setinterval() en el angular para hacer tus consultas